# Why does my STEP file cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: step

I'm writing aerodynamic design software and want to export the geometry a user specifies as a STEP file. I've managed to generate a STEP file that to my inspection appears complete, but when I try to open it with FreeCAD, I get a segmentation fault. What's wrong with my file?

I've tried changing the entity type for the edge_curve to something besides line, but I keep getting the same error. I've also tried opening the file using Solidworks, but it is also unable to open the file.

Here's the error message from FreeCAD:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f609a911f20]
#1  0x7f6009b06bd4 in StepShape_EdgeCurve::EdgeGeometry() const from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libTKSTEPBase.so.7+0x4
#2  0x7f600d92ae4e in StepToTopoDS_TranslateEdgeLoop::Init(opencascade::handle<StepShape_FaceBound> const&, TopoDS_Face const&, opencascade::handle<Geom_Surface> const&, opencascade::handle<StepGeom_Surface> const&, bool, StepToTopoDS_Tool&, StepToTopoDS_NMTool&) from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libTKSTEP.so.7+0x10de
```

There's more than that, but these lines seem to be the most relevant. Can anyone pinpoint where I've gone wrong?

**EDIT**

I've made the changes suggested and now FreeCAD will open, but nothing shows in the design space. No errors are thrown either. I'm not sure what's going on now.

```
ISO-10303-21;
HEADER;
FILE_DESCRIPTION ( ( 'STEP AP203' ) , '1' ) ;
FILE_NAME ( 'test_plane.stp' , '', ('Author'), (''), 'MachUpX', 'MachUpX', 'Unknown' ) ;
FILE_SCHEMA ( '' );
ENDSEC;

DATA;
#15 = SHAPE_DEFINITION_REPRESENTATION ( '', #16 , #101 ) ;
#16 = PRODUCT_DEFINITION_SHAPE ( 'test_plane' , 'NONE' , #18 ) ;
#18 = PRODUCT_DEFINITION ( 'NONE' , 'NONE' , #19 , #20 ) ;
#19 = PRODUCT_DEFINITION_FORMATION ( 'version1' , 'NONE' , #21 ) ;
#20 = PRODUCT_DEFINITION_CONTEXT ( 'NONE' , #23 , 'NONE' ) ;
#21 = PRODUCT ( 'no1' , 'test_plane' , 'Generated by MachUpX' , ( #22 ) ) ;
#22 = PRODUCT_CONTEXT ( 'NONE' , #23 , 'aeronautics' ) ;
#23 = APPLICATION_CONTEXT ( 'AP 203' ) ;
#200 = MANIFOLD_SOLID_BREP ( 'v_stab_right' , #201 ) ;
#201 = CLOSED_SHELL ( 'NONE' , ( #202 , #310 , #418 ) ) ;
#202 = ADVANCED_FACE ( 'NONE' , ( #203) , #204 , .T. ) ;
#203 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE' , #209 , .T. ) ;
#204 = PLANE ( 'NONE' , #205 ) ;
#205 = AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D ( 'NONE' , #206 , #207 , #208 ) ;
#206 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.000000 , 0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#207 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -1.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#208 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.000000 , -1.000000 , -0.000000 ) ) ;
#210 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 211 , .T. ) ; 
#211 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #212 , #214 , #216 , .T. ) ;
#212 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #213 ) ;
#213 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#214 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #215 ) ;
#215 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#216 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #217 , #218 ) ;
#217 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#218 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #219 , 0.2254588471561799 ) ;
#219 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.994469 , 0.105034 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#220 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 221 , .T. ) ; 
#221 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #222 , #224 , #226 , .T. ) ;
#222 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #223 ) ;
#223 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#224 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #225 ) ;
#225 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#226 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #227 , #228 ) ;
#227 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#228 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #229 , 0.22545914553885527 ) ;
#229 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.997007 , 0.077315 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#230 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 231 , .T. ) ; 
#231 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #232 , #234 , #236 , .T. ) ;
#232 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #233 ) ;
#233 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#234 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #235 ) ;
#235 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#236 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #237 , #238 ) ;
#237 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#238 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #239 , 0.22544175959974602 ) ;
#239 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.999243 , 0.038895 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#240 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 241 , .T. ) ; 
#241 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #242 , #244 , #246 , .T. ) ;
#242 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #243 ) ;
#243 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#244 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #245 ) ;
#245 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#246 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #247 , #248 ) ;
#247 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#248 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #249 , 0.2252781083976028 ) ;
#249 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.998859 , -0.047756 , -0.000000 ) ) ;
#250 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 251 , .T. ) ; 
#251 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #252 , #254 , #256 , .T. ) ;
#252 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #253 ) ;
#253 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#254 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #255 ) ;
#255 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#256 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #257 , #258 ) ;
#257 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#258 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #259 , 0.07824649394376136 ) ;
#259 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.000010 , -1.000000 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#260 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 261 , .T. ) ; 
#261 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #262 , #264 , #266 , .T. ) ;
#262 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #263 ) ;
#263 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#264 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #265 ) ;
#265 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#266 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #267 , #268 ) ;
#267 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#268 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #269 , 0.22527736125091588 ) ;
#269 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.998859 , -0.047753 , -0.000000 ) ) ;
#270 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 271 , .T. ) ; 
#271 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #272 , #274 , #276 , .T. ) ;
#272 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #273 ) ;
#273 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#274 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #275 ) ;
#275 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#276 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #277 , #278 ) ;
#277 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#278 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #279 , 0.22544172256288283 ) ;
#279 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.999243 , 0.038895 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#280 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 281 , .T. ) ; 
#281 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #282 , #284 , #286 , .T. ) ;
#282 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #283 ) ;
#283 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#284 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #285 ) ;
#285 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#286 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #287 , #288 ) ;
#287 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#288 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #289 , 0.22545905822782863 ) ;
#289 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.997007 , 0.077315 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#290 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 291 , .T. ) ; 
#291 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #292 , #294 , #296 , .T. ) ;
#292 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #293 ) ;
#293 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#294 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #295 ) ;
#295 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#296 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #297 , #298 ) ;
#297 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#298 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #299 , 0.22545886333367593 ) ;
#299 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.994469 , 0.105034 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#300 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 301 , .T. ) ; 
#301 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #302 , #304 , #306 , .T. ) ;
#302 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #303 ) ;
#303 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#304 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #305 ) ;
#305 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#306 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #307 , #308 ) ;
#307 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#308 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #309 , 8.294702139732885e-07 ) ;
#309 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.007167 , 0.999974 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#209 = EDGE_LOOP ( 'NONE' , ( #210 , #220 , #230 , #240 , #250 , #260 , #270 , #280 , #290 , #300 ) ) ;
#310 = ADVANCED_FACE ( 'NONE' , ( #311) , #312 , .T. ) ;
#311 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE' , #317 , .T. ) ;
#312 = PLANE ( 'NONE' , #313 ) ;
#313 = AXIS2_PLACEMENT_3D ( 'NONE' , #314 , #315 , #316 ) ;
#314 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.000000 , 0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#315 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -1.000000 , 0.000000 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#316 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.000000 , -1.000000 , -0.000000 ) ) ;
#318 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 319 , .T. ) ; 
#319 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #320 , #322 , #324 , .T. ) ;
#320 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #321 ) ;
#321 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#322 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #323 ) ;
#323 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#324 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #325 , #326 ) ;
#325 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#326 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #327 , 0.2254588471561799 ) ;
#327 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.994469 , 0.105034 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#328 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 329 , .T. ) ; 
#329 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #330 , #332 , #334 , .T. ) ;
#330 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #331 ) ;
#331 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#332 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #333 ) ;
#333 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#334 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #335 , #336 ) ;
#335 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#336 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #337 , 0.22545914553885527 ) ;
#337 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.997007 , 0.077315 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#338 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 339 , .T. ) ; 
#339 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #340 , #342 , #344 , .T. ) ;
#340 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #341 ) ;
#341 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#342 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #343 ) ;
#343 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#344 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #345 , #346 ) ;
#345 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#346 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #347 , 0.22544175959974602 ) ;
#347 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.999243 , 0.038895 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#348 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 349 , .T. ) ; 
#349 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #350 , #352 , #354 , .T. ) ;
#350 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #351 ) ;
#351 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#352 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #353 ) ;
#353 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#354 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #355 , #356 ) ;
#355 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#356 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #357 , 0.2252781083976028 ) ;
#357 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( 0.998859 , -0.047756 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#358 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 359 , .T. ) ; 
#359 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #360 , #362 , #364 , .T. ) ;
#360 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #361 ) ;
#361 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#362 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #363 ) ;
#363 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#364 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #365 , #366 ) ;
#365 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#366 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #367 , 0.07824649394376136 ) ;
#367 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.000010 , -1.000000 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#368 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 369 , .T. ) ; 
#369 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #370 , #372 , #374 , .T. ) ;
#370 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #371 ) ;
#371 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#372 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #373 ) ;
#373 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#374 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #375 , #376 ) ;
#375 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#376 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #377 , 0.22527736125091588 ) ;
#377 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.998859 , -0.047753 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#378 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 379 , .T. ) ; 
#379 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #380 , #382 , #384 , .T. ) ;
#380 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #381 ) ;
#381 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#382 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #383 ) ;
#383 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#384 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #385 , #386 ) ;
#385 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#386 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #387 , 0.22544172256288283 ) ;
#387 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.999243 , 0.038895 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#388 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 389 , .T. ) ; 
#389 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #390 , #392 , #394 , .T. ) ;
#390 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #391 ) ;
#391 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#392 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #393 ) ;
#393 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#394 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #395 , #396 ) ;
#395 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#396 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #397 , 0.22545905822782863 ) ;
#397 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.997007 , 0.077315 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#398 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 399 , .T. ) ; 
#399 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #400 , #402 , #404 , .T. ) ;
#400 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #401 ) ;
#401 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#402 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #403 ) ;
#403 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#404 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #405 , #406 ) ;
#405 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#406 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #407 , 0.22545886333367593 ) ;
#407 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.994469 , 0.105034 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#408 = ORIENTED_EDGE ( 'NONE' , * , * , 409 , .T. ) ; 
#409 = EDGE_CURVE ( 'NONE' , #410 , #412 , #414 , .T. ) ;
#410 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #411 ) ;
#411 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#412 = VERTEX ( 'NONE' , #413 ) ;
#413 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#414 = LINE ( 'NONE' , #415 , #416 ) ;
#415 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#416 = VECTOR ( 'NONE' , #417 , 8.294702139732885e-07 ) ;
#417 = DIRECTION ( 'NONE' , ( -0.007167 , 0.999974 , 0.000000 ) ) ;
#317 = EDGE_LOOP ( 'NONE' , ( #318 , #328 , #338 , #348 , #358 , #368 , #378 , #388 , #398 , #408 ) ) ;
#419 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#420 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#421 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#422 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#423 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#424 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#425 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#426 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#427 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#428 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -0.100000 ) ) ;
#429 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , 0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#430 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , 0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#431 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , 0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#432 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , 0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#433 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850712 , 0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#434 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -2.850713 , -0.039123 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#435 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.075733 , -0.049881 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#436 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.301004 , -0.041113 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#437 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.525788 , -0.023681 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#438 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE' , ( -3.750000 , -0.000000 , -2.100000 ) ) ;
#418 = B_SPLINE_SURFACE_WITH_KNOTS ( 'NONE' , 3 , 3 , ( ( #419 , #420 , #421 , #422 , #423 , #424 , #425 , #426 , #427 , #428 ), ( #429 , #430 , #431 , #432 , #433 , #434 , #435 , #436 , #437 , #438 ) ) , .UNSPECIFIED. , .F. , .F. , .F. , .UNSPECIFIED. , .UNSPECIFIED. , ( 0.0, 1.0 ) , ( 0.0, 0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4444444444444444, 0.5555555555555556, 0.6666666666666666, 0.7777777777777777, 0.8888888888888888, 1.0 ) , .UNSPECIFIED.) ;
#101 = ADVANCED_BREP_SHAPE_REPRESENTATION ( 'NONE' , ( #200 ) , #103 ) ;
#103 = GEOMETRIC_REPRESENTATION_CONTEXT ( 3 ) ;
ENDSEC;
END-ISO-10303-21;
```

Comment: Please don't rely on open source tools for debugging this. I would check the *.err files from SolidWorks importer instead.

Comment: I had a look at the beginning of your file and there are a few errors.
`FILE_NAME` has more than 2 attributes. You are missing `FILE_SCHEMA` in the header also. Probably those errors are not the problem though.
The first attribute of `SHAPE_DEFINITION_REPRESENTATION` should be a string. `APPLICATION_CONTEXT` is misspelled at `#23`. There might be more mistakes...

Comment: Another syntax error; according to the documentation of Part 21 of STEP, a real number with exponent should be with capital E (123.45E9, not 123.45e9). (There are also many other errors in some of your instances...)

Answer (score 1):

FreeCAD relies on Open CASCADE Technology (OCCT) library for reading STEP file.
If you will open your STEP file in CAD Assistant (free 3D viewer based on OCCT) you will see the following output in Message Window generated by OCCT reader:

```
20:29 Errors on Reading Header Entity N0.6:HeaderSection_FileSchema
20:29 Parameter #1 (schema_identifiers) is not a LIST
      Error occurred transferring STEP file!
      C:/test.stp
20:29 Count STEP Reader Failures for 'test.stp'
       -----    -----------
           1    F: Parameter #1 (schema_identifiers) is not a LIST
           1    F:SHAPE_DEFINITION_REPRESENTATION: Count of Parameters is not 2 for shape_definition_representation
           1    F:CLOSED_SHELL: Parameter n0.3 (face) : Entity has illegal type
          20    F:ORIENTED_EDGE: Parameter n0.4 (edge_element) not an Entity
          40    F:VERTEX: Count of Parameters is not 1 for vertex
           1    F:B_SPLINE_SURFACE_WITH_KNOTS: Parameter n0.9 (u_multiplicities) not a LIST
           1    F:B_SPLINE_SURFACE_WITH_KNOTS: Parameter n0.10 (v_multiplicities) not a LIST
           1    F:GEOMETRIC_REPRESENTATION_CONTEXT: Count of Parameters is not 3 for geometric_representation_context
          Nb Total:66  for 8 items
```

These message could help to figure out what is wrong in STEP file, or at least what OCCT reader dislikes in the file.

There is a question, though, why writing STEP writer from the scratch and not using some existing library? I suppose that geometry structure to be exported is rather simple to make an own STEP writer worth efforts.

Comment: You're right about using an existing library. I decided to give up on doing it myself and am using the FreeCAD Python modules instead. This could be helpful though if I decide to retry my original approach.